# Does accessing UI controls inside ComDataPacket.OnPacket needs thread synchronization?

Tags: delphi, tcomport

I have a `ComPort1` and a `ComDataPacket1` on my form and `ComDataPacket1.ComPort:= ComPort1;`. I see that there is a properties `SyncMethod` and I guess that `TComPort` creating a thread when `ComPort1.Connected:=true;`.

Recently I realized that every UI access from `OnExecute` event of Indy `IdTCPServer` component needs to be Synchronized with MainThread so is it true for TComPort? How to do this(Indy has a class to doing this)?

I am reading data from com port like this(data is sent as packet so `ComDataPacket1` is very useful):

```
procedure TForm2.ComDataPacket1Packet(Sender: TObject; const Str: string);
begin
    Label1.caption:= str;
end;
```

I am working on a project and sometimes I got famous "Your application has stopped working" message box(When my program is closed). I am suspecting this error is because of that.

Comment: You can discover the answer yourself. Set a breakpoint in the event handler. Is it running in a separate thread, or in the main one? Unless it's in the main thread, you need to shift any UI code to the main thread via `Synchronize`, `Queue`, or messages.

Comment: I already did. I've tracked thread count in the Windows Task Manager and when I connect the `ComPort1` thread count increased by one. But I don't have any experience or knowledge about threading. Also the thread created inside `TComPort` and this makes it more complex. May you give me any reference about it?

Comment: Tracking the thread count does not tell you which thread context is actually calling the `OnPacket` event handler. For example, some of Indy's components have a `ThreadedEvent` property to control whether certain events are triggered by the main thread or worker threads. So inside of the `OnPacket` event, you need to call `GetCurrentThreadId()` and compare it to the RTL's `MainThreadID` global variable. If they match, then the UI can safely be accessed directly, otherwise you must synchronize access.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , as you said I've used `GetCurrentThreadId()` and it's result is same as `MainThreadID`, so synchronization is not necessary. Thanks.